What's the difference in scope between the tags [opcodes] and [script]?
I've seen opcodes pop up on a lot of questions lately. I was wondering how the scope of that tag differs from script. Should opcodes perhaps be merged into script?

I think this makes sense.

Sure, if that's your preference @Murch. I don't feel strongly about it. Perhaps there is an argument that the opcodes tag could be for questions about specific opcodes and the script tag could be for questions on how to construct scripts or script execution generally. But feel free to merge them.

If we went with your suggestion, we should probably go through the questions tagged with [tag:script] and retag them to use [tag:opcodes] where appropriate. I'm not sure whether the distinction is worth the effort.
